# Android Streaming Audio Lag Increases Over Time

Tags: java, android

I am receiving base64 encoded PCM audio data from a microphone, adding it to a LinkedBlockingQueue, decoding it, and releasing it to an AudioTrack for playback while adding the same data to a StringBuilder in order to form a Google Cloud Speech-To-Text request with it.

The audio playback is fine for the first five seconds or so, after which the audio output latency becomes significant. I am at a loss for how to fix this issue, because calling LinkedBlockingQueue.size() always returns 0, and I do not know how to get the actual amount of data in the LinkedBlockingQueue. I have tried tweaking the audio buffer size, and writing audio data at an offset. Any assistance would be appreciated.

The audio playback code:

```
    class AudioTrackThread implements Runnable {
        private BlockingQueue<String> dataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        AudioTrackThread() {

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                StringBuilder audioString = new StringBuilder();

                if (track != null) {
                    track.flush();
                    track.release();
                }

                int bufferSize = 20 * AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                AudioTrack.Builder b = new AudioTrack.Builder();
                b.setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder().setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT).setSampleRate(sampleRate).
                        setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO).build());
                b.setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize);
                b.setPerformanceMode(AudioTrack.PERFORMANCE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
                b.setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                b.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).
                        setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).build());
                track = b.build();

                track.setVolume(2f);

                track.play();
                byte[] data = null;

                while (!stopToggle && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                    try {
                        final String dataBase64 = dataQueue.poll(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        audioString.append(dataBase64);

                        if (dataBase64 != null) {
                            data = Base64.decode(dataBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        } else {
                            data = null;
                        }

                        if (data == null || data.length == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        int offset = 0;
                        while (offset < data.length) {
                            int bytesWritten = track.write(data, offset, data.length - offset, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
                            offset += bytesWritten;
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Queue size:" + dataQueue.size() + "; Bytes written: " + offset +
                                " Under-run cnt: " + track.getUnderrunCount());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Thread exception: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }


                track.stop();
                track.flush();
                track.release();

                //Google Speech-To-Text code below

                speech.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            dataQueue.add(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using android studio, run the app and monitor(profiler) the application performance. however, it looks you are encountering memory-leak